# Combine three custom post type in function.php

Tags: wordpress

I have a function in my functions.php which calculates an average user rating. It is for Custom Post Types and works well. The problem is it only works for one type and I am sure there must be a neater way then having to repeat the function three times. The problem seems to be this line

```
<code>
$child_posts = types_child_posts('business-reviews', 'restaurant-cafe-rev', 'travel-tip-review');
</code>
```

Here is my full code - if anywone could guide me. Thanks

```
<code>
// Adds Calculation of average and shortcode for ratings
add_shortcode('rating-average', 'rating_average_func');
function rating_average_func()
{
$child_posts = types_child_posts('business-reviews', 'restaurant-cafe-rev', 'travel- tip-review');

$sum = 0;
$num = 0;
foreach ($child_posts as $child_post) {
    if(isset($child_post->fields['ratings']))
    {
        $sum += $child_post->fields['ratings'];
        $num ++;
    }
}
$average = 0;
if($num>0)
{
    $average = $sum/$num;
}
$res = $average;
if($average==0) $res = 0;
if($average>0.001 && $average<0.5)$res = 0.5;
if($average>0.501 && $average<1) $res = 1;
if($average>1.001 && $average<1.5) $res = 1.5;
if($average>1.501 && $average<2) $res = 2;
if($average>2.001 && $average<2.5) $res = 2.5;
if($average>2.501 && $average<3) $res = 3;
if($average>3.001 && $average<3.5) $res = 3.5;
if($average>3.501 && $average<4) $res = 4;
if($average>4.001 && $average<4.5) $res = 4.5;
if($average>4.501 && $average<5) $res = 5;
//... here put more condition ...
return $res;
}
//Add shortcode for Reviews Count
add_shortcode('reviews_total', 'reviews_total_func');
function reviews_total_func()
{
$child_posts = types_child_posts('business-reviews', 'restaurant-cafe-rev', 'travel-tip-review');
return count($child_posts);
}
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used that plugin...

Did you try this?

```
$child_posts = types_child_posts(array('business-reviews', 'restaurant-cafe-rev', 'travel-tip-review'));
```